# overirde spring security config

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application, which has spring security configured. I want to override the spring security config with my own implementation. my custom implementation is inside the jar. if the jar is in classpath then the application should take that spring security config from jar otherwise it should use config provided by the application.

the code in my application looks something like this

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityConfiguration {
....
}
```

i am not allowed to make any change in the application code but inside the jar i am allowed to do anything. is there any way by which I can tell spring to pick spring security config from jar instead of provided in class

Comment: Well, "lowest precedence" means, that this config will picked last. How about a higher precedence? `@Primary` can also be used to mark a bean as the primary candidate for injection

Comment: You need to add @EnableWebSecurity on top of @ EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation. Also let your SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.